# help with array

Tags: php, arrays

What am i doing wrong here? The username string is less than 2 chars but it still dont set error[]?

Register:

```
$errors = array();

$username = "l";

    validate_username($username);

if (empty($errors)) {
   echo "nothing wrong here, inserting...";
}

if (!empty($errors)) {

    foreach ($errors as $cur_error)
        $errors[] = '<li class="warn"><span>'.$cur_error.'</span></li>';
}


function validate_username($username) {

$errors = array();

if (strlen($username) < 2)
    $errors[] = "Username too short";
else if (strlen($username) > 25)
    $errors[] = "Username too long";

return $errors;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `validate_username($username);` to `$errors = validate_username($username);`

Your function is affecting a local variable named `errors`, not the global `errors` that you may have been expecting.

Further, your code can be cleaned up a little bit as follows

```
$username = "l";
$errors   = validate_username($username);

// No errors
if ( empty($errors) ) {
   echo "nothing wrong here, inserting...";
}
// Errors are present
else {
    foreach ( $errors as $cur_error ) {
        $errors[] = '<li class="warn"><span>'.$cur_error.'</span></li>';
    }
}

function validate_username($username) {
    $errors = array();
    $len    = strlen($username);

    if ( $len < 2 ) {
        $errors[] = "Username too short";
    } elseif ( $len > 25 ) {
        $errors[] = "Username too long";
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are not assigning the return value of `validate_username()` to any variable.

Try

```
 $errors = validate_username($username);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not returning it the right way, you need:

```
$errors = validate_username($username)
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to assign `$errors`

```
  $errors = validate_username($username);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**//TRY THIS INSTEAD**

$errors = array();

$username = "l";

**$errors = validate_username($username);**

if (empty($errors)) {
   echo "nothing wrong here, inserting...";
}

if (!empty($errors)) {

    foreach ($errors as $cur_error)
        $errors[] = '<li class="warn"><span>'.$cur_error.'</span></li>';
}


function validate_username($username) {

$errors = array();

if (strlen($username) < 2)
    $errors[] = "Username too short";
else if (strlen($username) > 25)
    $errors[] = "Username too long";

return $errors;
}
```